# Adding lists of Composables?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I have found that

```
val list: List<@Composable ()-> Unit> = listOf({Text("Cat")}, {Text("Dog")})
```

works, but

```
val list: List<@Composable ()-> Unit> = listOf({Text("Cat")}) + listOf({Text("Dog")})
```

produces the error "`@Composable` invocations can only happen from the context of a `@Composable` function" on the first `Text()`.

Why is it that adding lists works fine with things like

```
val list: List<String> = listOf("Cat") + listOf("Dog")
```

but doesn't seem to work with Composables? Is there a way how I can add lists of Composables to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in behavior between the two scenarios is related to how Jetpack Compose handles the `@Composable` functions and the context in which they are invoked.

In the first scenario:

```
val list: List<@Composable ()-> Unit> = listOf({Text("Cat")}, {Text("Dog")})
```

Both `Text("Cat") and Text("Dog")` are wrapped in @Composable lambda expressions within the list. When you use the list directly, the lambda expressions are invoked within the context of a @Composable function.

In the second scenario:

```
val list: List<@Composable ()-> Unit> = listOf({Text("Cat")}) + listOf({Text("Dog")})
```

Here, you are using the `+` operator to concatenate two lists. The resulting list contains two `@Composable` lambda expressions, but they are not automatically invoked within a `@Composable` context.

To Better understand, try with this example

```
@Composable
fun MainView() {
    val list: List<@Composable () -> Unit> = combineComposableLists()

    // Important: Render each composable in the combined list
    list.forEach { composable -> composable() }
}

@Composable
fun combineComposableLists(): List<@Composable () -> Unit> {
    val list1: List<@Composable () -> Unit> = getList1()
    val list2: List<@Composable () -> Unit> = getList2()

    return list1 + list2
}

@Composable
fun getList1(): List<@Composable () -> Unit> {
    return listOf(
        { Text("Cat") },
        { Text("Dog") }
    )
}

@Composable
fun getList2(): List<@Composable () -> Unit> {
    return listOf(
        { Text("Fish") },
        { Text("Bird") }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update what I ended up on: Since I *really* wanted everything in a single line, I specified the type for each list separately.

```
val list = listOf<@Composable ()-> Unit>({Text("Cat")}) + listOf<@Composable ()-> Unit>({Text("Dog")})
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but good enough for me.